# Apply i18n to a Hibernate backed Spring Web API

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a couple of Hibernate entities stored in a DB that I want to internationalize.
For example my "country" entity:

```
@Table(name = "country")
public class Country {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Integer id;
  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
}
```

What I now want to do is enhance the API that handles the retrieval of the countries to return the country entry in the appropriate language. (e.g. adding `?lang=en` to the query)

For that I have a country controller:

```
@RestController
@Api(tags = "Country")
public class CountryController {

  private final CountryDao countryDao;

  public CountryController(CountryDao countryDao) {
      this.countryDao = countryDao;
  }

  @ApiOperation(value = "View a list of available countries.")
  @GetMapping(path = "/entity/countries")
  public Iterable<Country> getCountries() {
      return countryDao.findAll();
  }
}
```

How would I do that?

I have thought of adding a new `i18n` table that holds message keys with the available translations.
But in the end I still would like the API to return a simple JSON entry containing only the country name that the user is interested in, without having to attach all available translations.

I tried with `AttributeConverter` to mark the fields on the entity with `@Convert(converter = I18nConverter.class)`and search the `i18n` table for the matching key, but with that approach I don't have access to the specified language in the query...

```
public class I18nConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {
  private final I18nEntryDao i18nEntryDao;

  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
      ...
  }

  @Override
  public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
      ...
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to internationalize actual database values. Instead, use ISO country codes and let the client handle presentation.

Comment: The country entities are just an example. I have other entities which contain more text which can't just be displayed as ISO code and need translation.

Comment: If they "need translation", that indicates they're enumerated values and should be stored as codes that are then internationalized by the UI.